# Mails sometimes are sent and sometimes not

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5.4, beanstalkd, forge

First here is the code of the mailable function:

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class InvitationRequest extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Invitation')
                    ->view('emails.invitation.request')
                    ->text('emails.invitation.request_plain');
    }
}
```

And here is the call of the function:

```
Mail::to($invitation->email)->send(new InvitationRequest($invitation));
```

This code works find 100% of the time on a local machine with homestead,  mailtrap and beanstalkd. But when it doesn't work online.

I use forge to manage the server and still mailtrap and beanstalkd (exact same config). I have a worker running.

When I try to send, let's say 5 emails, with the same exact form. Sometimes, I get mail 1 and 3, sometimes 2 and 4, etc.

I have no failed_jobs on the database and no errors on the log file.

Has someone encounted this problem? How can I fix it?

EDIT: Problem seems to be from beanstalkd. I change to redis and everything works find.

Comment: are you using something like Mandrill or Mailgun, because in that case you can see if the mails are trying to send and if the problem is the mailbox or laravel itself.

Comment: How do yousend multiple emails? Did you just do Mail::to($invitation->email)->send(new InvitationRequest($invitation)); 5 times?

Comment: No, i'm using smtp and mailtrap to catch them

Comment: @ troyer, yes. Fill the form several times in a row.